# Calling a function with with args using its reference in Scala

Tags: scala

Consider the following code:

```
object HelloIntelliScala {
  def main(args : Array[String]) = {
    println(callAnyFunc(funcWithNoArgs))

    val l = callAnyFuncWithArgs("bingo") (funcWithArgs)
    println(l)

    val l2 = callAnyFuncWithArgs(21) (funcWithArgs2)
    println(l2)

  }

  type noArgCallBack = () => Any

  def funcWithArgs(inp : String) : Any = {
    println("Func with arg called, arg value is: " + inp)
    "Hello " + inp + "!"
  }

  def funcWithArgs2(inp : Int) : Any = {
    println("Func with arg called, arg value is: " + inp)
    "Hello, integer " + inp + "!"
  }

  //how do i call this function?
  def funcWithArgs3(inp : Int, name : String) : Any = {
    println("Func with 2 args called, arg values are: " + (inp, name))
    "Hello, multiple args " + (inp, name) + "!"
  }

  def funcWithNoArgs() : Any = {
    println("Function with no args was called!")
    "Hello NO_ARGS"
  }

  def callAnyFunc(callback : noArgCallBack) : Any = {
    callback();
  }

  def callAnyFuncWithArgs[A, B](arg : A)(f : A => B) : Any = {
    f(arg);  //how do I pass variable args here
  }
}
```

I need a generic way to call any function with arguments, just like the one without arguments. Please note that the argument list to be passed in can be variable and we do not know the arguments type's at compile time. Also I do need the Any return type since I'll need to use this value for post processing. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just to clarify, there are more than one such functions that I need to call using the generic calling mechanism.

Comment: The [loan pattern](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SYGN/Loan) helps, but I'm still not able to figure out how to make it work for a variable arg list.

Comment: Have updated the code to include the loan pattern allowing me to call functions which accept only one argument, how to expand it for variable arg list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala doesn't abstract over method arity. Or, in other words, there's no way to do that without writing boilerplate for each arity.

Fortunately for you, Miles Sabin wrote all that boilerplate with [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless#readme).

Comment: Thanks, I think this might just fit the bill; let me run some test cases and I'll get back.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer tentatively although I haven't been able to deep dive into Shapeless, it looks like it will address my needs. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like:

```
def funcWithArgs(args: String*) = args foreach println
def callAnyFuncWithArgs[A, B]
  (args: A*)(f: (A*) => B) = f(args: _*)
```

and then call funcWithArgs as a partially applied function:

```
callAnyFuncWithArgs("bingo")(funcWithArgs _)
```

Comment: And you can set return type to `B`.

Comment: +1, good point, but actually, we can remove the return type since B return type will be inferred by the compiler (we are invoking a function that itself returns B); of course this only applies if invoking f() is the sole operation to be performed; otherwise, then yes, OP should enforce B return type explicitly

Comment: Thanks virtualeyes, I did already change the code to above, but as Daneiel has pointed out I still have to write a bunch of boilerplate code. Good point about the return type!

Comment: @cracked_all I have updated the answer to show possible use case based on varargs; if you need specific arity with mixed type, maybe Shapeless or some form of category theory feuled madness is required ;-)

Answer (score 1):

this could probably work with function currying...
have a look here: http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/function-currying-in-scala
 then you can wrap up the function  to call in a curried function (Function.curried) and simply stuff in the args at some point and call it then

Comment: This is interesting but it ties me down into specifying the arg types at compile time. Also how do I use this for calling multiple such functions?